# Is there a way to force Wordpress to overwrite plugin files on installation?

Tags: wordpress

There are some 3rd party Wordpress plugins that do not support automatic updates. So, if you have v1.0 of a plugin already installed and you try to install a new version (e.g. v1.1), you will end up getting the message:

```
Destination folder already exists. /home/.../.../...
```

This leaves two options, neither of which i'd like to use: Uninstall & re-install the plugin, or manually upload the new files via FTP.

In /wp-admin/includes/class-wp-upgrader.php line 428 I see this code:

```
public function install_package( $args = array() ) {
    global $wp_filesystem, $wp_theme_directories;

    $defaults = array(
        'source' => '', // Please always pass this
        'destination' => '', // and this
        'clear_destination' => false,
        'clear_working' => false,
        'abort_if_destination_exists' => true,
        'hook_extra' => array()
    );

    $args = wp_parse_args($args, $defaults);

    ...
```

Is it possible to add a line to my theme's functions.php file to  re-declare 'clear_destination' as true, and thereby forcing Wordpress to overwrite plugin files when I upload them?

Thanks

Answer (score 3):

I kept digging and think I found a solution. If I create a custom plugin I can re-declare the options by using the 'upgrader_package_options' filter:

```
function override_plugins( $options ) {

    $options['clear_destination'] = true;
    $options['abort_if_destination_exists'] = false;

    return $options;
}
add_filter( 'upgrader_package_options', 'override_plugins' );
```

Answer (score 0):

No, that's not possible. You would need to edit the core files.

However you could install a plugin on the relevant site(s) that would take care of the problem for you: http://w-shadow.com/blog/2010/09/02/automatic-updates-for-any-plugin/

Or you could incorporate an updater framework within your plugin, which makes it possible to serve updates from private repos(eg not WP): https://github.com/afragen/github-updater

Alternatively, you could use something like [WPPusher](https://wppusher.com/), which can automatically update the plugin whenever an update is pushed to Github / BitBucket. I personally use this plugin for testing dev versions of plugins I'm building.

Answer (score 0):

In addition to Phill Healey's answer, an alternative service to WPPusher dedicated to Wordpress Developement is [WP Package Editor (WP2E)](https://wp2e.recuweb.com/)

The Package Installer overwrite plugin source and log installations into a panel to monitor script versions, upgrades and status.